# How do I prevent a browser from downloading a file and automatically changing its name

Tags: django, python-3.x, http

I have a project which reads the database composition into a compose environment variable file `.env`. I use django to read it and generate it.

Part of the code is as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

content = "Stringtest"
filename = ".env"
response = HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/plain')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(filename)
return response
```

When I download the file using brower, the `preceding comma` is automatically removed and the file name is changed to `env` instead of the required `.env`

How can I change the file name to remain the same?

Comment: Could you try wrapping the filename in quotes? `filename="{0}"`. Which webserver are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington I'm using `Django`'s own webserver. I modify my code `'response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(filename)'`, but it doesn't seem to be working. In Windows Chrome, I download `env.txt`, and in Linux firefox, the download screen displays `.env`, but tt gets rid of the `comma` and becomes the `env` when I type `ls` in the download directory